# ng-bind-html not working from ng-click fucntion

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web

I am trying to write HTML based on values that I receive, I want to do that in ng-click()
Trying to write HTML value from that ng-click
$scope.writeDiv = $sce.trustAsHtml(' ');

This is not working, How can I make this work?

Comment: What have you already came up with, show some code

Comment: there are two controllers
<globalController>
<controller1>
if Done from here does not work for ng-click, works on load time
<controller2>
works on ng-click
div is here